# Paper.js intersection pulling node position out of path object

Tags: javascript, vector, paperjs

I am trying to utilise paper.js to get a node and its handle positions resulting from an intersection of two paths. I don’t need to render the result, I only need to position for further processing.
The two open paths are as the following image illustrates:

[image]

I would know the exact coordinates of the red highlighted node and handles.
How can I pull this information out of the path object?
Does that work with non-closed paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get [path intersections with `path.getIntersections()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getintersections-path) and [split it with `path.splitAt()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#splitat-location).

The [path.firstSegment.handleIn](http://paperjs.org/reference/segment/#handlein) and [path.lastSegment.handleOut](http://paperjs.org/reference/segment/#handleout) will give you the handle positions.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me to find the solution in my context!